# Yellow error screen appended to response

Tags: asp.net, session, iis-6, application-pool

I have an application that is getting yellow asp.net error screens appended to the response. The page will look normal, and then have the yellow screen below the Html. I have narrowed this error down to the application reseting during the response, and the session dying. So if I start loading a page, and save the web.config, it gives me a session-related error appended to the page. I am going to use the sessionstate service to fix this, but I am curious if anyone has ever seen a yellow screen actually appended to their application html. This website even uses customerrors="on" with redirects to 500 error pages. How can I prevent this from happening? Do you think the sessionstate service will help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you have a web control on the page that in turn calls another web app or service to generate the response, and that web app is the one that is erroring....

Comment: never thought of that! this could be it

Answer (score 0):

Any response.Flush calls in your code? That's the only thing i could think of, but no, never seen that happen.